# Can't validate numbers in my string

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to check that a string

- contains only digits and
- the first digit is 0, and
- the whole string has at least 8 digits and maximum 25

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[0][0-9]\d{8-25}$/', $ut_tel))
```

Comment: Are the numbers supposed to be contiguous or can there be spaces, dashes, etc?

Comment: no spaces or other stuaff, just digits

Comment: removing [0] did not help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/^0\d{7,24}$/
```

It seemed to work [here](http://regexr.com?387um).

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex pattern

```
^(0[0-9]{7,24})$
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lV1gG7)</kbd>

Comment: be careful minimum is 9 numbers now and maximum 26

Answer (score 1):

If I was you, I'd do each check separately. This way you won't have issues in the future, should you decide to remove one of them or add additional checks.

(**Note to all potential downvoters:** I realize the question asked for a regex way, but since that was already provided in other answers - I think it is good to have a different approach as an answer as well.)

```
function validateNumber($number){
    if(!is_numeric($number))
        return false;
    if(strlen($number)>25 || strlen($number)<8)
        return false;
    if(substr($number, 0, 1) != 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

var_dump(validateNumber('0234567')); // shorter than 8
var_dump(validateNumber('02345678')); // valid
var_dump(validateNumber('12345678')); // doesn't start with 0
var_dump(validateNumber('02345678901234567890123456')); // longer than 25
```